# Swift Invalid redeclaration class default init

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, initialization

I'm new to Swift and was playing around with classes. In the documentation(https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) it states that if default values for all of its properties are provided, an initializer is created automatically. However, in the code below XCode gives me a **Invalid redeclaration of 'Phone'** error message. I'm unsure how this is happening.

```
class Phone {
    
    var maker = "iphone"
    var price = 300
    var isBroken = false
   
}

var iphone12 = Phone()
```

Comment: You must have `Phone` declared somewhere else as well (another file?) or you need to clean your build. That code compiles fine.

Comment: That code alone is not causing the issue. You have somewhere else `enum Phone`, `struct Phone`, `class Phone` etc. In other words, you have 2 declarations of `Phone`, which one to take? That's what's saying the error. Check the other files or this one.

Comment: Thank you @jnpdx and @Larme. I was testing the behavior of structs as well and had `struct Phone` at the beginning of the file. I guess you cannot have the same name of struct and class simultaneously???

Comment: No, you cannot. If you could have multiple types with the same name, getting the compiler to differentiate between the two would be complicated (if not impossible). For example, with your line `var iphone12 = Phone()` there would be no way for the compiler to know whether your wanted the `class` or `struct`

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

“Phone” is used in another place in your files even if it is not declared as a class it can cause errors like this.